# How can I select a post and all its related posts?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a question-and-answer website like SO. I have a table like this:

```
// qanda
+----+----------+----------------------+---------+------+
| id |   title  |       content        | related | type |
+----+----------+----------------------+---------+------+
| 1  | a title  | a content            | NULL    | 0    |
| 2  |          | a content            | 1       | 1    |
| 3  | a title  | a content            | NULL    | 0    |
| 4  |          | a content            | 1       | 1    |
| 5  |          | a content            | 3       | 1    |
+----+----------+----------------------+---------+------+
/*  type column:     "0" means it is a question, "1" means it is a answer
    related column:  it contains the id number of its own question
*/
```

Now I need to select a question and all its own answers based on a `id` number. *(that `id` number can be either the id of a question or the id of an answer)*.

Here is my current query:

```
SELECT * FROM qanda WHERE id = :id OR related = :id
```

My query works as well only when `:id` is the id of a question. *(I mean it doesn't work correctly if `:id` be the id of a answer)*.

---

Here is **expected result:**

```
assuming either :id = 1 or :id = 2 or :id = 4
+----+----------+----------------------+---------+------+
| id |   title  |       content        | related | type |
+----+----------+----------------------+---------+------+
| 1  | a title  | a content            | NULL    | 0    |
| 2  |          | a content            | 1       | 1    |
| 4  |          | a content            | 1       | 1    |
+----+----------+----------------------+---------+------+
```

As I mentioned above, I need to select those three rows if `:id = 1` or `:id = 2` or `:id = 4`. How can I do that?

Comment: It would make more sense to divide your schema into a Questions and Answers table, and then have a foreign key constraint for each answer to the parent Question.  This current design is a recipe for disaster

Comment: @Alex I will change my database design *(creating two separated table for questions and answers)* like what you said in next version of my website .. Currently I need to solve the problem I'm faced with.

Comment: How much data do you currently store, if you can migrate to a new database design now I'd highly recommend it.  You are going to hit some serious performance bottle necks as you scale with this current design,

Comment: @juergend My query returns just one row when `:id = 2` ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query should work. The query is divided in 4 parts that are unioned together. Description of each query:

1. Returns question if `:id` is a question
2. Returns answers if `:id` is a question
3. Returns question if `:id` is an answer
4. Returns answers if `:id` is an answer

Query:

```
select q.*
  from quanda q
 where q.id = :id
   and q.type = 0
 UNION ALL
select a.*
  from quanda a
 where a.related = :id
 UNION ALL
select q.*
  from quanda a
  join quanda q
    on q.id = a.related
 where a.id = :id
   and a.type = 1 
 UNION ALL
select a2.*
  from quanda a1
  join quanda a2
    on a2.related = a1.related
 where a1.id = :id
   and a1.type = 1
```

Comment: Just one question, why my question has earned two downvotes? What's wrong with it?

Comment: Educated guess: I suspect some downvoted because they fundamentally disagree with your db design.  Personally, I don't think that's a valid reason to downvote. Downvotes should be for (as it says when you hover over the downvote image) questions that show a lack of effort, are not useful or unclear.  Though not everyone may agree with what you are trying to do, I think that you explained yourself clearly, especially when I compare with 90% of the SQL questions asked on SO.

Comment: I agree with @sstan comment, although I disagree with your database design I did actually upvote your post due to the time you obviously put in to creating it.  It's not of low quality so I don't believe it deserved down votes!